# Paypal Not Accepting Ipn Url

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to setup Paypal IPN for the past couple of days !

And every time I get the error :

**

> We were unable to validate the URL you have entered. Please check your
>   entry and try again.

**

The IPN url I am trying to set it : http://www.geniusforums.net/misc.php?do=paypal_ipn

I did a dns test to see if the problem was with that but everything seems to be fine!

http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools#dnsReport|type=domain&&value=geniusforums.net

It is accepting the IPN of a different site hosted on the same server, but just not the current IPN. I asked a couple of my friends also to check the IPN with their Paypal accounts, assuming the problem was with just my account, but they respond they are also getting the same error!

I just checked the IPN url using the IPN Testing in Paypal developer, and well, see for yourself:

**

> We are sorry we could not connect to this URL. Please make sure it was
>   entered correctly.

**

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I cant load anything from this domain: http://www.geniusforums.net/ It doesn't look like a website exists at this address at all. Just for fun I navigated to http://www.geniusforums.com and that resolves successfully to a parked site. I would check that the server is up or that the domain or url is correct.

Comment: How could that be? I have designed the site and everything in the past couple of days! :o

Comment: confirm that your website exists at `http://www.geniusforums.net`?

Comment: [Isitdownrightnow.com](http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/geniusforums.net.html) shows its up. And as a proof [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/aUQb7V2.png)

Comment: Just checked [**Isup.me**](http://www.isup.me/geniusforums.net) and even that says its [**UP**](http://i.imgur.com/eJAGxBh.png)

Comment: Have you checked your web server logs to see if it's getting hit but returning an error?  geniusforums.com is loading for me fine, but when I try your IPN URL, or even just misc.php without the URL params...I get nothing from that.

Comment: @AndrewAngell yes, I checked and they seem to be fine!

Comment: What does that mean?  You're seeing that the script is getting hit, but it's just returning a 200 response?

Comment: @AndrewAngell I am not sure what you mean by _You're seeing that the script is getting hit, but it's just returning a 200 response_ . Could you explain it please?

Answer (score 1):

Try using create ipn settings in https://www.paypal.com/home this account instead of https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think I read somewhere that the IPN URL must be SSL hence https did a quick search however could not find the reference. May be the solution though.